# Error sending Android build to codenameOne Buildserver

Tags: android, codenameone

I tried to send my CodenameOne application to the build server, but I keep getting this build server error: http://pastebin.com/Rr2GLQWR

(It contains too many characters for Stackoverflow..)

It is running in the simulator and the last line of the error says

```
(build should be done)
```

I found a possible solution giving it the `android.gradle = false` build hint, but that didn't matter though.
I have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file named `.class` within your distribution?

Did you change the java language level to Java 8 or something like that in the project after it was created?

You can't do that if you originally created a Java 5 project see  http://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html

Comment: You were right.. again,  as usual. My CLDC.jar was - however - an old version though I recently updated it. Thank you once more for your great support!